# My J-1 visa expires 7 days before my flight ticket. What should I do? Does it depend on the flight company?

Tags: visas, j1-visas, us-visa

My J1 visa states that it expires on 1st of Aug. But my return flight is on 7th of Aug. Do I need to get a new VISA? What should I do?

Comment: What's your citizenship.

Comment: See the linked Q&A for details. The visa expiration date is not relevant. It is the date your program ends that is relevant.